# MySQL INSERT WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have a stupid little SQL query which isn't working and i can't figure out why

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` = '294' INSERT INTO 'auth' VALUES 'false'
```

I want to select the row which pertains to the id (294) and insert the value false into the 'auth' column, but i keep getting a #1064 error.

Can someone correct the above?

embarrassed,

Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just want to update the '294' record and set its 'auth' value to 'false', correct? If so:

```
update tablename set auth = 'false' where id = 294;
```

Comment: @Brian TechToolbox thank you both :) i can't mark this answered for another couple of minutes but this is the one. Thanks again, Dan

Comment: to convert this into a PHP query, would $sql = "update tablename set (auth = 'false') where (id = '$bus_id')"; be the right syntax?

Comment: mysql_query("update tablename set auth='false' where id = '$bus_id'");

Answer (score 1):

you want to do an update not an insert.

```
Update 'tablename' set 'auth' = 'false' where 'id' = '294'
```